# Procedural textures squashed!

Tags: texturing, procedural

i followed this tutorial to create a marble procedural texture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vV9zZ3Tu7SI&t=143s.

The problem is that the texture appears squashed on the short side of my object (40x40x2cm). How can I solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node, and if it is still not good, apply the *Scale* of your object

Comment: Or Smart UV Unwrap your texture *(Edit Mode -> U -> Smart UV Unwrap)*